# Abaqus replay file not consistent with with node labels displayed in GUI

Tags: python, abaqus

I wanted to create some sets in an Abaqus model with a python script, using the replay file as reference for syntax. The GUI shows these node labels:
[(I'm concerned with node 2733)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XpIP.png)

Querying the node also gives the same label, along with its coordinates:

```
Coordinates of node 2733 :1.477119995E+03,1.527209961E+03,-647.083008
```

But when I check the replay file after picking this node and creating a set manually, this is what I find:

```
a = mdb.models['LM735P_fail_P000_Sub_30'].rootAssembly
n1 = a.instances['PART-1-1'].nodes
nodes1 = n1[2718:2719]
a.Set(nodes=nodes1, name='loadnode_test')
#: The set 'loadnode_test' has been created (1 node).
```

What could be the reason for this discrepancy? (the node label shows up as **2718**)

This did not happen when I created an "Unsorted" set, which only adds to my confusion.

Comment: This is not possible. I have checked and the node labels were the same. Have you changed/remeshed the model? This is the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: Well my teammate thought the same, since I was working on making a submodel and had removed some elements. He opened another instance of the original model and ran into the same problem. This only occurs when I use - 
`a.Set(nodes=nodes1, name=setname)` .

But there is no problem when I do the same with - 
`a.SetFromNodeLabels(name=setname, nodeLabels=(('PART-1-1', (node1,node2, node3, node4)), ),)` . I have no idea why this could be happening.